# User defined parameters not working on stored procedure sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm creating stored procedures to generate reports based on user based parameters as filters. I've already got almost every `SELECT` query working, but the final one which contains a bunch of `LEFT JOIN` ends up returning `NULL` in the entire table.

I execute the stored procedure like this:

```
exec promediosDot
        @periodo1a = 201612,
        @periodo1b = 201703,
        @periodo2a = 201712,
        @periodo2b = 201803,
        @periodo3a = 201812,
        @periodo3b = 201903,
        @tipGas = 'VENTAS'
```

This is the query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE promediosDot
    @periodo1a INT,
    @periodo1b INT,
    @periodo2a INT,
    @periodo2b INT,
    @periodo3a INT,
    @periodo3b INT,
    @tipGas NVARCHAR(6)
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        T1.HOMOLOG_VP, 
        PROMEDIO1 = ((T2.CANT_PERS1 + T3.CANT_PERS2 + T4.CANT_PERS3 + T5.CANT_PERS4) / 4),
        PROMEDIO2 = ((T6.CANT_PERS1 + T7.CANT_PERS2 + T8.CANT_PERS3 + T9.CANT_PERS4) / 4),
        PROMEDIO3 = ((T10.CANT_PERS1 + T11.CANT_PERS2 + T12.CANT_PERS3 + T13.CANT_PERS4) / 4)
    FROM 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM USOS_CP 
         WHERE PER_PRO > 201611) T1
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS1 
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo1a 
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T2 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T2.HOMOLOG_VP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS2 
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo1a + 1 
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T3 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T3.HOMOLOG_VP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS3 
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo1a + 2 
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T4 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T4.HOMOLOG_VP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS4 
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo1a + 3 
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T5 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T5.HOMOLOG_VP
    --
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS1 
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo2a 
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T6 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T6.HOMOLOG_VP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS2
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo2a + 1
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T7 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T7.HOMOLOG_VP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS3
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo2a + 2
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T8 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T8.HOMOLOG_VP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS4
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo2a + 3
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T9 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T9.HOMOLOG_VP
    --
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS1
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo3a
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T10 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T10.HOMOLOG_VP   
     LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS2
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo3a + 1
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T11 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T11.HOMOLOG_VP   
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS3
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo3a + 2
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T12 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T12.HOMOLOG_VP   
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
             HOMOLOG_VP, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_HR) AS CANT_PERS4
         FROM 
             DOTACION 
         WHERE 
             PERPRO = @periodo3a + 3
         GROUP BY 
             HOMOLOG_VP) T13 ON T1.HOMOLOG_VP = T13.HOMOLOG_VP   
GO
```

Results (extract):

```
HOMOLOG_VP  PROMEDIO1   PROMEDIO2   PROMEDIO3
---------------------------------------------
a3          NULL    NULL    NULL
a4          NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I'm not sure if it's just the nature of parameters not working until a certain point or not working on a sub query. The query works perfectly by writing the parameters by hand. Any help it's appreciated.

Comment: Gosh that looks like it could be simplified immensely. That could be a single query with a few aggregate columns and a case expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could come because your periodo is set for december as 201612 and if you add one it becomes 201613 instead of 201701. This is a problem of using integers for date values. As mentioned by Sean, this can also be converted to a simpler query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE promediosDot
        @periodo1a int,
        @periodo1b int,
        @periodo2a int,
        @periodo2b int,
        @periodo3a int,
        @periodo3b int,
        @tipGas nvarchar(6)

AS
SELECT  
    U.HOMOLOG_VP, 
    PROMEDIO1 = (   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 0, CAST( @periodo1a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END) 
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 1, CAST( @periodo1a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 2, CAST( @periodo1a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 3, CAST( @periodo1a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)) /4,
    PROMEDIO2 = (   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 0, CAST( @periodo2a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END) 
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 1, CAST( @periodo2a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 2, CAST( @periodo2a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 3, CAST( @periodo2a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)) /4,
    PROMEDIO3 = (   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 0, CAST( @periodo3a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END) 
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 1, CAST( @periodo3a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 2, CAST( @periodo3a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)
                  + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN D.PERPRO = CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, 3, CAST( @periodo3a AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01'), 112)  THEN D.ID_HR END)) /4
FROM USOS_CP  U
JOIN DOTACION D ON U.HOMOLOG_VP = D.HOMOLOG_VP
WHERE U.PER_PRO > 201611
AND (D.PERPRO BETWEEN @periodo1a AND @periodo1a + 3
    OR D.PERPRO BETWEEN @periodo2a AND @periodo2a + 3
    OR D.PERPRO BETWEEN @periodo3a AND @periodo3a + 3)
GROUP BY U.HOMOLOG_VP
ORDER BY HOMOLOG_VP;
```

Comment: Didn't saw that on my code, your code it's running perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I hope that you realized that I forgot to change the calculation in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have several parameters not being used in the code you posted. But you could greatly simplify that query. Something like this should be the same thing. No need to join to the same table over and over and over.

```
SELECT cp.HOMOLOG_VP
    , PROMEDIO1 = count(case when d.PERPRO >= @periodo1a and d.PERPRO <= @periodo1a + 3 then 1 end) / 4
    , PROMEDIO2 = count(case when d.PERPRO >= @periodo2a and d.PERPRO <= @periodo2a + 3 then 1 end) / 4
    , PROMEDIO3 = count(case when d.PERPRO >= @periodo3a and d.PERPRO <= @periodo3a + 3 then 1 end) / 4
FROM USOS_CP cp
left join DOTACION d on d.HOMOLOG_VP = cp.HOMOLOG_VP
WHERE cp.PER_PRO > 201611
group by cp.HOMOLOG_VP
```

Comment: I thought on doing something like that, but I'm not sure it'll work because the OP is using COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: Yeah, the procedure has 2 more querys that use those variables after the one I posted. I know my query it's rubbish but I need to distinct ID's each time (period), also yours loops eternally.

Comment: Couldn't test this because we didn't get table definitions or sample data. It was my shot in the dark. Oh well...next time post table definitions and it will be easier for people to help.